# Почему не работает ajax?

Tags: ajax

Пишу код на локальном сервере (Open Server) по примеру из видео. Но он почему-то не работает.
Вот HTML и JavaScript:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('#shop_ip').onclick = function() {
    ajaxGet();
  }
}

function ajaxGet() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'ip.php');
  request.send();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>AJAX</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" id="shop_ip" value="Показать мой IP">
  <div id="myip"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Вот PHP:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

У человека из видео точно такой же код и при этом у него после клика в консоли браузера выводится следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня же ничего не выводится:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как файлы расположены, если это важно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть некие подозрения что это видео не новое так сказать и в браузерах что то изменилось. Что теперь это выводится в другом месте, но это лишь мои мысли хочу узнать так ли это?
Вот "полазив" во вкладке network в хроме увидел следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто знает, подскажите пожалуйста. В чём дело? Буду рад любой помощи. Спасибо!

Ах, да вот что на странице где php код. Этим я хочу показать что php работает. С ним тоже вроде всё норм.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: во-первых, у тебя другой браузер, во-вторых, судя по скриншоту - видео очень старое, поэтому за вывод в консоль может что угодно отвечать. Правильнее смотреть именно на вкладке network - в котором как раз и показываются запросы.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за отклик! Видео действительно староватое - 2016 года. То есть правильно что я проверял работу ajax во вкладке network?

Comment: О том сработал ajax или нет, говорит - status code?

Comment: А то что ajax вернул я могу посмотреть в network => response?

Comment: в response - будет сырой ответ, в preview - обработанный, например json в удобном виде